# Ubuntu 20.04 samba share access issue

Tags: networking, nautilus, samba, file-sharing

I have an issue when trying to access my USB HDD connected to my router. It was working in 19.10 but after upgrading to 20.04. it stooped working.

I have configured the diskdrive on my router and get these options

network neighborhood: smb://my_share
ftp: ftp://192.168.0.1:21

when I insert connection into krusader for example ftp://192.168.0.1:21 it will connect to the drive and I can browse folders and files correctly and the connections is kept unless the crusader is not closed, but cannot play any movie or see any photo unless I download locally

when I insert connection smb://my_share then it follow two behavior types

- I have this line in smb.conf: client min protocol = NT1 (just to understand what I'm doing bellow)

1. it connects successfully, I can browse folders files, but cannot play anything out of the disk

- but in some point of time it disconnect me
- then the re-connection went to be timeout
- when I change above config command to 'client min protocol = CORE' and restart smbd I'm able to connect but again only for some time and nothing can be played

2. it did not connect and timed out connection and then I have to switch again the config line in smb.config to NT1 or CORE, depends what was there before

- but again nothing can be played/see and the timeout come after some time anymore

You see that I cannot do changes all the time and restarting the smbd every 10 minutes and cannot played anything from that disk

However in 19.10 I was able to see network drives in the nautilus under other location / network and then able to login with user/password
In 20.04 I cannot see this anymore in nautilus and hence cannot do anything on my shared drive

Can you please help on this topic, or should I downgrade samab to older version. I do not want to downgrade Ubuntu to 19.10 only for this reason, but if it will not work, I have to because in 20.04. it seems will not be working anymore.